# troubles with languages of google maps api (Crimea streets and ets)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, primefaces

I use Primefaces GMAP. All streets in Crimea names are in Ukrane language, but I need them in Russian. I tried to set map's language to ru

> (src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=ru")

but it didn't help.  Someone could help me? On google.com/maps site all this streets are in Russian.

Answer (score 0):

Gmaps will use user's preferred language in browser. Although, if you require you can override default setting (not recommended in general use case).
Here's a [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Localization) to localization docs.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=ru">
```